# osmx elevation data: no module named 'keys'

Tags: python, osmnx

I'm coming from R and new to Python, so I assume this is a novice question, but any help would be appreciated. I'm following along with this example to add elevation data to Open Streets Map data using the OSMnx package:
https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples/blob/master/notebooks/12-node-elevations-edge-grades.ipynb

When I type the first block of code

```
from keys import my_google_elevation_api_key
```

I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-384032deeff7> in <module>()
----> 1 from keys import my_google_elevation_api_key #replace this with your own API key

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keys'

-----------
```

(Note - I am using an API key from Google as instructed in the example. The code above is intentionally generic.) I'm using jupyter to type the Python code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author probably has a `keys.py` in which he defines the variable `google_elevation_api_key` and assigns it a key that he later uses to access the elevation API.

You could simply replace the import line

```
from keys import my_google_elevation_api_key
```

with this

```
my_google_elevation_api_key = '<your_api_key>'
```

Comment: For anyone else who may be similarly new, to make this work in the context of the example, I substituted the object name 'my_google_elevation_api_key' defined as suggested by @shad0w_wa1lk3r for the actual alphanumeric key in the 3rd code block, i.e. G = ox.add_node_elevations(G, api_key=google_elevation_api_key).